# In command line, putty remote shell doesn't work, but in GUI, it does work

Tags: ssh, putty

Using the GUI putty.exe, I can connect to my windows server and once it is connected, i can type any command like rename file or mkdir folder and they all work

However, using command line such as

```
putty -load test -m C:\users\test.txt
```

or using the GUI putty, but add 1 command to remote command in SSH under Connection, then the command doesn't get executed.

Can anyone explain to me why this is happening or how can i fix this? I am using FreeSSHd on windows 2008 server.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but try adding the /bin/bash directly after your command in the text file.  It will keep the window open and you can see what the output of the shell would be if you ran it from the gui.

```
; /bin/bash
```

For example if test.txt is running a script

```
bash myscript.sh

bash myscript.sh; /bin/bash
```

This is assuming bash.